# How to manage Sidekiq cron jobs with multiple workers

Tags: sidekiq, sidekiq-cron

I want to schedule periodic jobs, and I want to deploy multiple Sidekiq processes for increased throughput. I imagine this means multiple containers running `bundle exec sidekiq` (or `sidekiqswarm`), each invoking their Sidekiq initializer when they start up. The initializer would contain something like:

```rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.periodic do |mgr|
    mgr.register("* 4 * * *", "MyJob")
    mgr.register("* 4 * * *", "MyOtherJob")
    ...
```

I'm hoping Sidekiq will be smart enough to recognize that each process is registering the same things and not duplicate them? But what if I later redeploy with an updated configuration:

```rb
    mgr.register("* 4 * * *", "MyBetterJob")
    mgr.register("* 5 * * *", "MyOtherJob")
```

Will I now have MyJob and MyBetterJob both running at 4, and MyOtherJob running at 4 and 5? **How do I clean out the old crons?** This seems like a maintainance headache. **How do I just declare the desired current set of cron jobs?**

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48336258/708883) suggesting clearing out crons by deleting keys in Redis, but having multiple processes each doing that at once would be a mess. Is embedding the cron management within an [actor on the leader](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Leader-Election) the recommended practice?